# Toda vez que utilizo FindAll + Where no NodeJs acontece esse erro, alguém consegue explicar?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

estou com um problema para fazer uma busca utilizando node, sendo que também faço uso do Sequelize na aplicação. Alguém sabe o motivo?  **Quando faço a busca com o metodo findByPk ele encontra normalmente, o problema acontece justamente ao tentar buscar utilizando outro dado como referência**

Minha rota está assim:

```
router.post("/buscar", UsuarioController.buscar);
```

Ela está chamando esse controller:

```
async buscar(req, res){
        const sUsuario = req.body;
        try{
            const objUsuario = await new UsuarioDAO().buscarUsuario(sUsuario);
            return res.json(objUsuario).status(200);
        }catch(erro){
            return res.json(erro).status(404)
        }
    },
```

O UsuariosDAO está da seguinte forma:

```
buscarUsuario(usuario){
        try{
            const objUsuario = mUsuario.findAll({
                where:{
                    email: usuario.email
                }
            }).then((success)=>{
                return objUsuario;
            }).catch((error)=>{
                return error;
            });
        }catch(erro){
            return erro;
        }
    };
```

Meu mUsuario é a model do usuário, segue ela aqui também:

```
const { Model } = require("sequelize")
const Sequelize =  require("sequelize"),
 database = require('../database/index')

const Usuario = database.define('usuarios', {
 id:{
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true
 },
 nome:{
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
 },
 email:{
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
 },
 senha:{
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
 }
},{
 timestamp: false
})
//Usuario.sync({force: true})
module.exports = Usuario
```

Para complemento, segue a conexão, que está no "database":

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize"),
    dbConfig = require("../config/database"),
    connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig) 
module.exports = connection
```

Toda vez que faço a busca ele não retorna o resultado, apenas a query: Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `nome`, `email`, `senha`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `usuarios` AS `usuarios` WHERE `usuarios`.`email` = 'email@email.com';

Comment: Está faltando informações na sua pergunta, por exemplo onde está o seu arquivo de conexão? O que tem dentro desse `mUsuario` que está dando um `findAll`?

Comment: Verdade, enviei o complemento das informações.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso o usuarioDOA deve fazer a conexão com o banco de dados.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
buscarUsuario = async(usuario){
        try{
            const objUsuario = await connection()
                .select("*")
                .from("nome_do_banco_de_dados")
                .where({email: usuario.email})
            .then((success)=>{
                return objUsuario;
            }).catch((error)=>{
                return error;
            });
        }catch(erro){
            return erro;
        }
};
```

Comment: Obrigado! Complementei as informações, pois estavam resumidas. Nesse caso estou utilizando o sequelize, e ele funciona normalmente quando a busca é pela primary key ou quando é uma findall sem o "where", mas com o where não funciona.